# Intelligence as measured by DNA tests

Tags: genetics, genomics, intelligence

Suppose a person has an IQ of 130, as measured by a standard IQ test, when he is 18 years old. He then goes on to develop severe mental illness, which reduces his IQ to 100. After this, he takes a DNA-intelligence test, like the one offered by GenePlaza, which claims to measure his intelligence from his DNA. Will this test show an IQ closer to 130 or 100?

Note that mental illness is governed by a combination of genetic and environmental factors.

Comment: Note that the "IQ test" on GenePlaza is not meant to be taken seriously: *'[The results come with disclaimers saying the results don’t mean much yet, because they predict only about 5 points of IQ. “I hope people are not getting it thinking that this is a true measure of their intelligence,” says Alain Coletta, a bioinformatics scientist and the founder of GenePlaza.'](https://www.geneplaza.com/blog/en/dna-test-iq-score)*

Comment: What are the causes of this severe mental illness in your scenario?

Comment: @Remi.b As I said, my understanding is that mental illnesses like schizophrenia are governed by a combination of genetic and environmental factors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about intelligence tests, not about biology.

Comment: @ David I'm basically asking if a person's true IQ can be accurately predicted from his DNA. How is that not a biology question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on the data that genetic model was developed from. I would suspect that most research on genetic factors of IQ has been performed in healthy, normal adults, so the model will predict IQ from DNA as if the subject were a healthy, normal adult (whether they are or not). It's unlikely that the DNA-IQ model was developed using a large cohort of mentally ill people, so the model may produce inaccurate results when applied to those people. I would expect the test to produce a score closer to 130 (if it is indeed an accurate model, which I will not discuss here).

Even if there are genetic predictors of the mental illness, it's likely not a 1:1 correspondence between DNA features and the illness, so this effect would be diluted when correlating against a third variable like IQ.